# Image manipulation, theory, formulas and pseudo code

Tags: image-manipulation

I'd like to know where read materials to learn how to manipulate image via code. 
I just created a simple software to read any pixels from an image and i'm able to apply some simple code to modify it, for example i can create a gray scale image using this (pseudo)code:

```
foreach(pixel in image){
 red = pixel.r;
 green = pixel.g;
 blue = pixel.b;
 alpha = pixel.a;

 gray = (red + green + blue) / 3; 

 pixel.r = gray;
 pixel.g = gray;
 pixel.b = gray;
}
```

Do you know websites (or a books) where i can find any informations about image manipulation applied to software development ?

Comment: You will get more useful answers if you can describe your mathematical backgrounds. For example: are you familiar with convolution / image filtering? Color space? Linear algebra (matrix)? Otherwise this will only become a disparate list of resources with no clear definite answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a fast approach to this problem, you can use as solution wikipedia :) try out these links, there you'll find formulas too.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur
- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepia_(color)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepia_%28color%29)
  in the right box you find RGB %

I have to separate my answers because as new user i can post only 2 hyperlinks at once

Comment: i finish here : 

A great resource is this freeware book with source code:

 - http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/PHILLIPS/
   (9.3 mb)


Than, this book (http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Image-Processing-Computer-Vision/dp/0470643854/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) is not free... but is a really great resource (but you have a lot to read and learn :) ) 

Is really difficult to find pseudo code on image processing :( 

hey! and at last (but not the least) why you don't check github ? i'm sure you can find great code there!

Answer (score 1):

Try using MATLAB for an easy beginning:

[Image Processing with MATLAB](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~getreuer/matlabimaging.html)

Comment: MATLAB is a tool, it does not replace understanding of the fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

One good reference that starts with absolute basics and covers some interesting material is [Digital Image Processing Algorithms and Applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=VQs_Ly4DYDMC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) By Ioannis Pitas

Answer (score 1):

[HIPR Image Processing Learning Resources](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fulldemo.htm)

Answer (score 1):

[Graphics Gems (all volumes)](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=graphics%20gems&x=0&y=0) have terrific information about image processing (as well as all aspects of computer graphics).  Although the books are *not* tutorials, some of the gems are definitely written in a tutorial style.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with something simple and open source such as Processing. Here is a comprehensive tutorial that has many examples...

http://processing.org/learning/pixels/